# How to get Rhythmbox to sync album cover art to Android?

Tags: android, sync, rhythmbox

I have Rhythmbox syncing quite well with my Android phone. It automatically transcodes from FLAC to M4a and keeps the correct directory structure and track file names.  So far so good.

However, the sync process is not copying over the album art.  In each album directory I have a file called "cover.jpg" which Rhythmbox uses quite well, but it doesn't make the journey to my Android SD card.   On Banshee, the album art is copied, but it has a vexing array of other bugs which keep me from using it as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar setup with the exception that I do not transcode my flac files.  I found that I needed to embed the album art into the flac file itself using metaflac:

metaflac --import-picture-from="yourcover.jpg" "yourmusicfile.flac"

You'll have to make a script for this process, but I have a perl script that you can use that just needs modifying to match your directory locations:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $artist;
my $album;
my $filename;
my $cover_filename;

if($#ARGV != 0)
{
    print("Usage: add_album_art_flac.pl <TOP DIR>\n");
    exit;
}

print("Getting artist album info...\n");
my @flac_album_artist = `find . -type f -name \"*.flac\" -exec metaflac --with-filename --show-tag=\"Artist\" --show-tag=\"Album\" {} \\\;`;
print("Got artist album info\n");

foreach my $flac_file (@flac_album_artist)
{
    if($flac_file =~ /^(.+):ARTIST=(.+)$/)
    {
        $filename = $1;
        $artist = $2;
    }
    elsif($flac_file =~ /^(.+):ALBUM=(.+)$/)
    {
        if($filename ne $1)
        {
            undef $artist;
            print("ERROR: Failed Sanity Check.  Dying...");
            die;
        }
        elsif(defined $artist)
        {
            $album = $2;
            $cover_filename = "/home/fred/.cache/rhythmbox/covers/$artist - $album.jpg";

            print("Fetching $cover_filename...\n");
            system("metaflac --import-picture-from=\"$cover_filename\" \"$filename\"");

            if($? == -1)
            {
                print("Failed to add $cover_filename to $artist - $album\n");
            }
            else
            {
                print("Successfully added $cover_filename to $filename\n");
            }
        }

        undef $artist;
    }
    else
    {
        print("ERROR: Bad line.  Dying...\n");
        die;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even know this was possible with FLAC files.  Been using RubyRip, Picard and QuodLibet and none of these has this option.  Will have to think about the pros/cons of this approach before I do it.  In general, however, I like the idea...thanks!